# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_file_info() codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file

I need to findout the size of my file before modifying it using codeigniter.
so I used

```
$file='foldername/filename';
$fileinfo = get_file_info($file);
    $data['filesize'] = $fileinfo['size'];
    $size = $data['filesize'] / 1024; //Converting to KB
    if($size>=10){
        //statements
    }
    else
    {
        //statemets
    }
```

But when executing it shows the above error. Can somebody help me , please?

Comment: you must load helper before use functions

`$this->load->helper('file');`

Comment: @ Ali Qorbani Thank you for your response. Yes I understand.But the question is already answered.

Comment: so sorry I didn't checked answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the below line at the top of page

```
$this->load->helper('file');
```

`get_file_info` is a function of the file helper. So if you don't load this first, the program doesn't know where to look for this function.

Comment: @Adrian, Happy that it worked. Please accept the answer. So others can easily findout